# Add unused partition `Solaris reserved 1` to mirrored zpool

Tags: ubuntu, partition, zfs, mirror

I am running an Ubuntu 20.04 LTS server for data storage on a mirrored ZFS pool. The server has the following devices and their primary targeted usage:

1. `/dev/sdc` -> SSD INTEL SSDSC2BA10; Linux system root and UEFI partition
2. `/dev/sda` -> WDC WD100EFAX-68; 1st HD for mirrored zfs pool
3. `/dev/sdb` -> WDC WD100EFAX-68; 2nd HD for mirrored zfs pool

The system is up and running and the designated services do what they should for some months now. However, during one of my system administration days (thinking about a second potential pool and a new backup strategy etc.) I had a closer look once again on the current device and pool layout. Here I stumbled across an unexpected detail. The two mirrored HDs include small potentially unused partitions which I can't remember to have created explicitly or used at any time. They are Typed as `Solaris reserved 1` and after some research that is what they are used for, meaning, to use the zpool under Solaris if on plans to do so. So first, here is the output of `pool status data`:

```
  pool: data
 state: ONLINE
status: Some supported features are not enabled on the pool. The pool can
    still be used, but some features are unavailable.
action: Enable all features using 'zpool upgrade'. Once this is done,
    the pool may no longer be accessible by software that does not support
    the features. See zpool-features(5) for details.
  scan: scrub repaired 0B in 0 days 06:13:40 with 0 errors on Sun Aug  8 06:37:42 2021
config:

    NAME                                    STATE     READ WRITE CKSUM
    data                                    ONLINE       0     0     0
      mirror-0                              ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD100EFAX-68LHPN0_7PJX67XC  ONLINE       0     0     0
        ata-WDC_WD100EFAX-68LHPN0_7PJWTGAC  ONLINE       0     0     0
```

And here is the output of `sudo fdisk -l`(omitting all the loop devices created by the snaps:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD100EFAX-68
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 24D7FF03-3872-0848-9274-6EAFE1800914

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sda1         2048 19532855295 19532853248  9.1T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sda9  19532855296 19532871679       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdb: 9.1 TiB, 10000831348736 bytes, 19532873728 sectors
Disk model: WDC WD100EFAX-68
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: CDE74412-3237-EA46-AA85-4B8201751A7F

Device           Start         End     Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdb1         2048 19532855295 19532853248  9.1T Solaris /usr & Apple ZFS
/dev/sdb9  19532855296 19532871679       16384    8M Solaris reserved 1


Disk /dev/sdc: 93.16 GiB, 100030242816 bytes, 195371568 sectors
Disk model: INTEL SSDSC2BA10
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 085B61AA-0648-47EA-9A2E-CE9307103753

Device       Start       End   Sectors  Size Type
/dev/sdc1     2048   1050623   1048576  512M EFI System
/dev/sdc2  1050624 195368959 194318336 92.7G Linux filesystem
```

If I never plan to mount the zpool under Solaris, is is safe to remove `/dev/sdb9` and `/dev/sda9` without breaking the overall zfs filesystem on the mirror? ?

Is there a way to reuse `/dev/sdb9` and `/dev/sda9`? Ideally I would not add additional partitions to the pool (which I know how to do) but to expand the existing `/dev/sda1` and `/dev/sdb1` which are part of the mirror to include the potentially unused disk space of the two smaller partitions.

Sorry if this is an too easy question for you....

Comment: `sdb9` is just 8 megabytes, do you really need it?

Comment: zfsonlinux always creates a GPT partition table with those two partitions when you give `zpool create` whole disks to work with.  It ensures that the partitions used by ZFS are properly aligned to sector boundaries (as seen in your fdisk output with the Start at sector 2048) and that they are exactly the same size (useful if you use different drive brand/models that are only approximately the same size).  It also ensures that there's enough free space before the pool data for the partition table itself and grub or other boot-loader.

Comment: BTW, that second partition has a type number (in hex) of `bf07` and is called "Solaris Reserved 1", but that doesn't mean it's **FOR** use with Solaris.  It's not used at all by ZFS, it's just a convenient, roughly appropriate partition type code to reserve the tiny amount of remaining space on the disk.  Just ignore it, it's not important, and it's not big enough to be of any use....I guess you could hide a few megabytes of data there if you wanted to.

Comment: Dear Romeo, thanks for the enlightenment. No, 8MB is not really something to worry about space-wise, I absolutely agree with you. It was more a matter of a) understanding what is going on here and b) my internal impetus to *order and clean-up* where it just bugs me that there are things with my server layout which I didn't explicitly set up and which I do not understand. The sector alignment reason is particularly interesting. Is there some documentation why such an alignment is beneficial for ZFS mirrors? In any case, thanks a lot.